# export svgs in bokeh for vbar_stack with hatch patterns

Tags: svg, bokeh

I wanted to export svg and it is executing but it gives no output after waiting a long time. Can you please help me out?

I wanted to have hatched vbar stack as output as svg. I have found it takes that much time for exporting svg.
Links: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/8192
Now I'm a bit confused whether it won't work for vbar plot or not?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import Title
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import Legend
from bokeh.io import export_svgs

output_file('stacked.html')

capacity = ['CO2_Cap', 'Min_RES_Quota', 'CO2_Tax', 'FIT']
types = ['Lignite', 'Coal', 'CCGT', 'OCGT','Wind Onshore', 'Wind Offshore', 'Solar']
colors = ["#9a7b5c", "#414141", "#c7dada", "#c7dada", "#5a67ff",'#00b8f2', '#fff340']

maxload = [90.03467675, 90.03467675, 90.03467675, 90.03467675]
Total_demand = [540.7686148, 540.7686148, 540.7686148, 540.7686148]


data = {'capacity' : capacity,
        'Lignite'   : [0,22.28330605,0,25.76575924],
        'Coal'   : [0, 0, 0,0],
        'CCGT'   : [52.12309276, 0.209356135, 52.12598273, 6.416971663],
        'OCGT'   : [10.1753325,20.35167058,10.1729694,22.18142626],
        'Wind Onshore': [90.66714923, 77.28982927, 90.6875821, 86.3713515],
        'Wind Offshore': [24.26075426, 53.92876756, 24.25201174, 60.265434],
        'Solar' : [90.1174063, 159.3567357, 90.0774928, 178.0811123]
        }

s1 = figure(x_range=capacity, plot_height=450,plot_width=655)


s1.vbar_stack(types, x='capacity', width=0.3, color=colors, source=data,
             legend=[value(x) for x in types], hatch_pattern=['dot', 'spiral', 'vertical_wave', 'right_diagonal_line', 'vertical_dash', 'left_diagonal_line', 'ring'])
s1.line(x = capacity, y = maxload, color="red", line_width=3, legend_label = "max_load")

s1.legend.location = "bottom_right"
s1.legend.click_policy="hide"
#s1.add_layout(Title(text="Total CO2 Emissions (in 10^6t) ", align="center"), "left")


show(s1)


from bokeh.io import export_svgs
s1.output_backend = "svg"
export_svgs(s1, filename="plot11111.svg")
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Bokeh 2.1.1 hatch patterns are not supported on the SVG backend. With those removed, your code above functions as expected.

Comment: So, you mean, hatched pattern doesn't support in SVG?

Comment: Bokeh cannot generate SVG output when hatch patterns are present.

Comment: Thanks for the Info. Is there any other library available for that such as matplotlib or plotly?

Comment: AFAIK plotly does not support any hatching at all (SVG or otherwise). Matplotlib might, but I don't know for certain.